# Error when importing HMM package (hmmlearn)

Tags: python, setuptools, attributeerror, hmmlearn

When I try to import the [hmmlearn](https://pypi.org/project/hmmlearn/) package with `import hmmlearn`, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-036832e0c673> in <module>
----> 1 import hmmlearn

~\Anaconda3\envs\py385\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\__init__.py in <module>
      9 try:
     10     import setuptools_scm
---> 11     __version__ = setuptools_scm.get_version(  # xref setup.py
     12         root="../..", relative_to=__file__,
     13         version_scheme="post-release", local_scheme="node-and-date")

AttributeError: module 'setuptools_scm' has no attribute 'get_version'
```

I'm in a python 3.8.5 env on a windows machine. In other environments on this machine (e.g. py 3.7) I don't get the error. Also on my MacOs machine in an 3.8.5 env I can import the package without any problems. In all cases I used `pip install hmmlearn` to get the package.

I uninstalled and re-installed the hmmlearn and the setuptools_scm package, but that didn't fix it.

It seems like the is a problem with my setuptools_scm package. How can this be fixed? Is there a way to completely remove the hmm package and all its dependencies and do a "clean" re-install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows and python 3.8.5. For me, uninstalling the hmmlearn and setuptools_scm and then reinstalling it with conda (I'm in a conda environment) fixed it.

So I did:

```
pip uninstall hmmlearn
pip uninstall setuptools_scm
```

and then

```
conda install -c conda-forge setuptools_scm
conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn
```

Also, I restarted the kernel in jupyter notebook.

But I'm not sure if that was really the problem, since I can't recreate the problem by uninstalling it over conda and reinstalling the packages over pip.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. Additionally to the pip uninstall I manually deleted the setuptools packages in C:\Users\Anaconda3\pkgs and then reinstalled everything like you said with conda install. That fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I came across the same issue. It was because I was missing the setuptools_scm. After installing it, the issue war solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was

`pip uninstall hmmlearn`

`pip uninstall setuptools_scm`

and then simply,

`pip install hmmlearn`

`pip install setuptools_scm`

and Kernel restart.

System setup:
Windows 10 Pro
Python 3.7.4 on conda 4.11.0